# Create a Multi Model Endpoint using AWS Sagemaker Boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, linear-regression, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker, multi-model-forms

I have created 2 models which are not too complex and renamed them and placed them into a same location in S3 bucket.

I need to create a multi model endpoint such that the 2 models have a same end point. 
The model i am using is AWS in built Linear-learner model type regressor.

I am stuck as to how they should be deployed.

Comment: Take a look https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/save-on-inference-costs-by-using-amazon-sagemaker-multi-model-endpoints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMaker's Linear Learner algorithm container does not currently implement the requirements for [multi-model endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-multi-model-build-container.html). You could request support in the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285&start=0).

You could also build your own version of the Linear Learner algorithm. To deploy the models to a multi-model endpoint you would need to build your own container that meets the requirements for multi-model endpoints and implement your own version of the Linear Learner algorithm. This sample notebook gives an example of how you would create your multi-model compatible container that serves MxNet models, but you could adapt it to implement a Linear Learner algorithm:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_bring_your_own/multi_model_endpoint_bring_your_own.ipynb